# Highcharts - Dealing with small values in Funnel chart

Tags: highcharts

When using the Funnel chart type, is there a way to deal with showing smaller value segments amongst larger values?

So for example, the default demo on the Highcharts site shows as:

[image]

But if the largest value is super big compared to the others, then the smaller values get hidden as they can't be shown in the funnel neck

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to somehow preserve the display of these in a proportional manner, maybe like how logarithmic scales could be used on other chart types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the funnel series doesn't have a logarithmic axis types.

Data in a funnel series is stacked, so this example of data will look like here with using the logarithmic y-axis type, which in my opinion will be not the best graphic chart interpretation.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2erg7psu/

I think that a better solution will be creating dummy data which will be shown on the graphic, but the real one will be used in the tooltip and data labels. As I mentioned, data in funnel is stacked, that makes an easier to create the dummy data - we can treat it as a percents value, where 100 is a whole funnel chart and 1 is just a 1% percent.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8ncv1wyk/

```
var data = [{
        y: 89.5,
        name: 'Website visits',
        value: 15654000
    },
    {
        y: 6,
        name: 'Downloads',
        value: 4064
    },
    {
        y: 3,
        name: 'Requested price list',
        value: 1987
    },
    {
        y: 1.5,
        name: 'Invoice sent',
        value: 976
    },
    {
        y: 1,
        name: 'Finalized',
        value: 846
    }
];
```

Treat it as a guideline and free to improve it - for example, you can add functionality which will parse the data to logarithmic values etc.